# How to render from multithreaded context

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, glfw, glew

In my following code.

```
class RenderOpengl
{
private:
    GLFWwindow* window = NULL;
public:
    RenderOpengl() { InitGLFW(); }
    void InitGLFW()
    {
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Test", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
            glfwTerminate();
            //  return -1;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Window Created";
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
        GLenum GlewInitResult;
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        GlewInitResult = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)   // Check if glew is initialized properly
        {
            std::cout << "Not able to initialize glew";
            //  return -1;
        }
    }

    void Render()
    {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            std::cout << "I am function number 555" << std::endl;
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
            std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
};

class ThreadClass
{
public:
    explicit ThreadClass(RenderOpengl* _gl) { gl = _gl; };
    RenderOpengl* gl;
    void RenderGL()
    {
        gl->Render();
    }
};



int main()
{
    RenderOpengl renderGL;
    std::thread t(&ThreadClass::RenderGL, ThreadClass(&renderGL));
    t.join();

//  renderGL.Render();
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

The rendering call in the Main function does not give any error.(`renderGL.Render()`)

But if I comment this line and call the same function in a separate thread it gives error 1282 , despite calling the `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)`.

Comment: glfw has it's own error reporting system. You might want to implement that and see if any of the glfw methods you call in the the thread already fail. Several glfw methods, especially those dealing with events and callbacks need to be called in the main thread and cannot be transferred to a thread.

Comment: Also note, that since you don't have any thread synchronization (mutex, ...), callbacks might interfere with the rendering. For example, the `framebuffer_size_callback` callback could be called after the context has been made current in the thread, but before the thread has called `glGetError`.

Comment: @BDL Thanks , i will check using glfw error reporting.